# Best practice loading custom language file Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

What is best practice.

Loading my custom language file in Codeigniter in the view or in the controller and then pass it from the controller to the view?

Controller example:

```php
$data = array(  'registrationSuccess'   => $this->lang->line('success'),
                'sayHello'              => $this->lang->line('hello'));

$this->load->view('view_registration', $data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should load the language file in your controller, but you should use it directly in your view.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Then I will stick with that.